# Stein real analysis execise 1.18

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Every measurable function is the limit a.e. of a sequence of continuous functions.

I already proved the finite-valued case i.e. any measurable $f:A\to\Bbb R$ can be approximated by a sequence of continuous functions a.e.
Now suppose $f:A\to\Bbb [-\infty,\infty]$: measurable and consider a truncations
$$g_n(x) = \begin{cases}
-n & f(x) = -\infty\\
n & f(x) = \infty\\
f(x) & o.w\\
\end{cases}$$
so that $g_n(x)\to f(x)$ for all $x\in A$. Since $g_n$ is a finite-valued measurable function, there is a sequence of continuous functions $g_{nk}:A\to\Bbb R$ such that $g_{nk}\to g_n$ as $k\to\infty$ a.e. So I expect $g_{nn}\to f$ as $n\to\infty$ a.e. Suppose $f(x)$ is finite. Then $g_n(x) = f(x)$ for all $n$. Let $\epsilon>0$ be given then for each $n$, there is $N$ so that for $k\geq N$, $|g_{nk}(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$. But $N$ depends on $n$ so I can't say there is a large $N$ s.t. $n\geq N$ implies $|g_{nn}(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

The double sequence $(g_{nk})$ does not help directly for a.e. convergence.

Do the same with convergence in measure. Convergence in measure is given by a metric.  In any metric space, $x _n \to x$ and $x_{nk} \to x_n$ as $k \to \infty$ implies that  $x_{n_ik_i} \to x$ for some $(n_i),(k_i)$. Finish the proof using the fact that convergence in measure implies a.e. convergence for  a subsequence.